# ANTLR4 Parser to Rescan Modified Input

Tags: antlr4

I want to support a feature similar to C++'s preprocessing macro replacement with ANTLR4 that requires the parser to back off a little bit and re-scan the modified input file.

For example, in standard C++:

```
#define a(x) b(x+1)
#define b(x) cc(x)
#define p1 a
....
    p1(p1);
```

In a standard C++ preprocessor, the identifier `p1` will be replaced by `a` giving rise to `a(a)` and then the C++ pre-processor will **rescan only this particular line** to see if the macro replacement should be applied again to turn the `a(a)` into `b(a+1)` and finally rescan the line to get `cc(a+1)`.

I'm able to implement the macro replacement feature with ANTLR4 by using `TokenStreamRewriter` when walking the parse tree.  But currently after the first replacement of `p1` with `a`, I need to save the modified input file and re-invoke the parser to scan the *whole input file* and obtain another parse tree instead of just rescanning the line I have replaced.  Is there any possible way to limit the re-scan to just the line I've modified (possibly regenerate part of the parse tree on-the-fly)? The input file is huge and there are a lot of such replacements, it would be a great performance issue to rescan the whole file after each single replacement.

Is there any feature in the Parser that can rollback the parsing to some previous "savepoint"?

Answer (score 5):

In ANTLR 4, by the time you are parsing it's too late to do significant manipulation of the input. You'll need to implement this feature in one of the following ways:

1. By externally preprocessing the input before passing the result to ANTLR. This is what we do for the performance analysis reported for the C11 grammar in the Adaptive LL(*) research paper.
2. Use a custom `TokenStream` implementation to preprocess the input tokens, so the input to the stream is the tokens found in the input and the output is a stream of preprocessed tokens ready for parsing.
3. Use a parser to perform the preprocessing, and then feed the result back to a token stream for language parsing (this is essentially implementing item 1 above using ANTLR itself).

If you find your approach reasonably straightforward and believe it would be useful in other languages, we would be grateful if you would document it to the best of your ability and contribute it back to the ANTLR project. Preprocessing is an area that I wouldn't consider solved at this point (at least not cleanly).